# Differential equation $y'' \cdot y^3 = 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I use these substitutions $y'=p(y)$ and $y'' = p' \cdot p$ to solve the equation, thus I have the consequence of the solution's steps:

$$ p'py^3 = 1 \implies p'p = \frac{1}{y^3} \implies \frac {dp}{dy} p = \frac {1}{y^3} \implies \int p dp = \int \frac{1}{y^3} dy \implies \\ p = \sqrt{C_1 - \frac {1}{y^2}}$$

Then I try to reverse my substitution and get:

$$ y' = \sqrt{C_1 - \frac {1}{y^2}}$$

What kind of differential equations is it? How do I have to solve it?

Comment: It's separable. Do exactly as before for $p$ and $y$.

Comment: Funnily, you've already done the difficult part; now just integrate $\frac {y'} {\sqrt {C_1 - \frac 1 {y^2}}} = 1$, i.e. $\int \frac {2 y' y} {2 \sqrt {C_1 y^2 - 1}} \Bbb d x= x + C_2$, i.e. $\frac 1 {C_1} \sqrt {2 C_1 y^2 - 1} = x + C_2$ etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already got an expression for $dy/dx$. Now separate it again to get

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{C_{1}-\frac{1}{y^{2}}}$

which is a standard integral to get $y(x)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+C_{1}^{2}(x+const)^{2}}{C_{1}}}$, where $const$ is a constant of integration.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply both sides by $2y'/y^3$. Then
$$ 2y'y'' = \frac{y'}{y^3}, $$
and we can recognise both sides as derivatives. Integrating once,
$$ y'^2 = A^2-\frac{1}{2y^2} = \frac{A^2 y^2-1}{y^2}, $$
and then you can rearrange to
$$ \frac{y^2y'^2}{A^2 y^2-1} = 1, $$
and then take a square root and integrate:
$$ x_0 \pm x = \int \frac{y \, dy}{\sqrt{A^2 y^2-1}} = \frac{1}{A^2} \sqrt{A^2y^2-1}, $$
which you can rearrange to find $A^4 (x_0 \pm x )^2 + 1 = A^2 y^2$, (which is a couple of hyperbolae).

Answer (score 0):

You have done more difficult part and seem to stumble at next step towards solution actually easy by separation of variables:

$ C_1 = c  ;  x = \int \dfrac{ c\,  y\,  dy}{\sqrt {y^2-c^2}}. $